# Please let me know any MySQL version which works with jdk 1.7

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I Installed JDK 1.7 and tried to connect to different MySQL database and Connector/J versions. But every time, I'm getting the following error when loading the driver:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
 at jdbc.JDBC.main(JDBC.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in java.sql.Driver
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:69)
 ... 3 more
```

Which MySQL driver version is compatible with JDK 1.7?

Comment: would you show your print stack trace?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with version incompatibilities. You're probably not putting the JDBC driver in the classpath correctly, or you're using an incorrect JDBC URL. Show us the exact error message.

Comment: @Jesper I have done exact process .. even If I had change to jdk 1.6 .Its works perfectly

Comment: @MohammodHossain run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at jdbc.JDBC.main(JDBC.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -     com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver is not abstract and does not override abstract method     getParentLogger() in java.sql.Driver
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:69)
    ... 3 more

Comment: I think mysql driver is not compatitable with your jdk

Comment: which mysql database version  are you using?

Comment: @MohammodHossain mysql-installer-5.5.20.0... That's why asking , compatible Mysql

Comment: Which Connector/J do you use, want exactly what does the code in `jdbc.JDBC.main` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -
com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver is not abstract and does not override
abstract method getParentLogger() in java.sql.Driver"
```

The method `getParentLogger()` was introduced to the `Driver` interface in Java 1.7.

Find a MySQL driver that supports Java 1.7 or switch back to Java 1.6.

Edit: Additional info:

I tested JDK 1.7.10 and a driver Jar named: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar`

Using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {
    System.out.println("Java version: "
            + System.getProperty("java.version"));
    Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            .newInstance();
    System.out.println("JDBC driver: " + driver.getMajorVersion() + "."
            + driver.getMinorVersion());
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME", "user", "pass");
    System.out.println("Connection: " + connection.getClass().getName());
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
Java version: 1.7.0_10
JDBC driver: 5.1
Connection: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
```

Possibly you have also a problem with the JDK/JRE Installation. When installing the JDK, it wants to update SQL drivers.
You might give it a try to uninstall and re-install the JDK.

Comment: Klimachewski : Ya i got this . But plz let Me know the compatibility MySql driver for jdk 1.7

Comment: Please let me know that , MySql driver which U have been used..?

Comment: @KumarKl - like I said (and Udo has just confirmed) if you are really using the pre-compiled drivers downloaded from the MySQL site, they should work without any problems.

Comment: Thank You both . I just Re-installed as of Your Suggestions. So its working .

Answer (score 3):

The exception message says this:

> "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Uncompilable source code** - com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in java.sql.Driver"

I think that the problem is that you (or someone else) have/has attempted to build the JDBC driver from source code and not noticed that there were compilation errors, and assembled the resulting broken ".class" files into a JAR file.

---

The standard Connector/J driver JAR files from the MySQL website should work with Java 7.  Certainly, I've never experienced any problems like this with them.

---

I'm more inclined to believe the evidence that I can see in the Exception message than your assurance that everything is "perfect":

- Are you sure that you are using a Connector/J JAR file that you downloaded from the MySQL Website?
- Did you check that MD5 checksum to make sure that you got the real thing?
- If you built from source, did you read the stuff in the docs/readme.txt about the JRE versions required to build correctly?
- Do you have some other (broken) copy of the drivers on your application's classpath?

Comment: Source code and everything is perfect . but the thing is the driver itself not getting load